# Java EE Maven Could not transfer artifact MANUAL.com.sun.messaging:imq:pom:4.1 from/to java.net

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jar

I am trying to revive an old Java EE project written by other developers.
I have manually solved most of the dependencies with "Manually install Artifact" from Netbeans.
Something seems wrong with MANUAL.com.sun.messaging:imq:jar. Any clues what is going wrong below?

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.999s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 06 23:21:18 CEST 2018
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project kmy-emi: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mydrm.kmy.emi:kmy-emi:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [junit:junit:jar:4.4 (test), org.apache.mina:mina-core:jar:1.0.2 (compile),
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.3.0 (compile),
org.slf4j:nlog4j:jar:1.2.25 (compile),
commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3 (compile),
xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1 (compile),
xom:xom:jar:1.1 (compile),
commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3 (compile),
org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.4.1.3 (compile),
org.apache.derby:derbynet:jar:10.4.1.3 (compile),
com.mydrm.kmy.util:sclib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT (compile),
com.mydrm.kmy.util:misc:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT (compile),
toplink.essentials:toplink-essentials:jar:2.0-58g (compile),
com.mydrm.kmy.util:xmlutil:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT (compile),
MANUAL.com.sun.messaging:imq:jar:4.1 (compile),
MANUAL.com.sun.messaging:jms:jar:4.1 (compile),
MANUAL.com.sun.jndi:fscontext:jar:4.1 (compile),
org.apache.derby:derbyclient:jar:10.4.1.3 (compile),
org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.3 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for MANUAL.com.sun.messaging:imq:jar:4.1: Could not transfer artifact MANUAL.com.sun.messaging:imq:pom:4.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): No connector available to access repository java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository) of type legacy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but perhaps it is related to `https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository`
 that no longer exists (take a look at the line to the right of `org.easymock:easymoc...`)

I found some posts about this on stack

[Maven site warning: The repository url 'https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository' is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098566/maven-site-warning-the-repository-url-https-maven-repository-dev-java-net-no)

Perhaps you can see if that will provide you with a lead.