# Differences between a multi-module project and a parent project

Tags: java, maven, maven-module

In multi-module project in Maven, we have a parent pom with modules defined in `<modules>` tag, and in each module, we define which the parent pom is.

- Why this two-way definition?
- Why not define the relationship between them just in the parent part of the modules
- How am I supposed to reuse modules if they are always bound to one parent?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Why this two-way definition?

It is not mandatory. It is a design choice.

> Why not define just in the parent?

If you define them only in the  `modules` tag of the parent pom, you will only use the reactor/aggregation feature of Maven.

**1) Aggregation (`<modules>` declaration in the super aggregator project) provides mainly these features:**

- Collects all the available modules to build
- Sorts the projects into the correct build order
- Builds the selected projects in order

Aggregation module is enabled by declaring the modules to aggregate in the parent pom:

```
<modules>
    <module>my-child</module>
    <module>my-other-child</module>
</modules>
```

But aggregation doesn't provide inheritance.

**2) Project inheritance (`<parent>` declaration in the child modules)  provides the inheritance of multiple things from the parent declaration to the child module :**

From the actual documentation, most elements from the parent POM are inherited by its children:

- `groupId`
- `version`
- `description`
- `url`
- `inceptionYear`
- `organization`
- `licenses`
- `developers`
- `contributors`
- `mailingLists`
- `scm`
- `issueManagement`
- `ciManagement`
- `properties`
- `dependencyManagement`
- `dependencies`
- `repositories`
- `pluginRepositories`
- `build`
- `plugin executions with matching ids`
- `plugin configuration`
- `reporting`
- `profiles`

Inheritance is enabled by declaring the parent artifact in the child poms:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<!-- You can note that groupId and version are not filled for the current project.
 These are optional as inherited from the parent -->
<artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
```

In fact, you can use project inheritance, project composition, none of them or both.

It is really a design choice that should be done according to the relation between the projects and their requirements.

You may refer to [this interesting point on the Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance) about these two features:

> **Project Inheritance vs Project Aggregation**
>
> If you have several Maven projects, and they all have similar
> configurations, you can refactor your projects by pulling out those
> similar configurations and making a parent project. Thus, all you have
> to do is to let your Maven projects inherit that parent project, and
> those configurations would then be applied to all of them.
>
> And if you have a group of projects that are built or processed
> together, you can create a parent project and have that parent project
> declare those projects as its modules. By doing so, you'd only have to
> build the parent and the rest will follow.
>
> But of course, **you can have both Project Inheritance and Project
> Aggregation**. Meaning, you can have your modules specify a parent
> project, and at the same time, have that parent project specify those
> Maven projects as its modules.

To illustrate using an example.

Here is a multi-module project's parent pom.xml.

```
<!-- PARENT POM -->
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>parent-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>child-module</module>
</modules>
```

And here is the Child Pom.

```
<!-- CHILD POM -->
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>chile-module</artifactId>
```

Here, `child-module` inherits `parent-demo`, but `parent-demo` does not use any inheritance.

And if you want, your `parent-demo` to also use inheritance, you can configure your `parent-demo` like below.

```
<!-- PARENT POM -->
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../parent-deps</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>parent-demo</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>child-module</module>
</modules>
```

And now, your `parent-demo` is also inheriting configurations from `parent-deps` which are cascaded down to `child-module` as well (unless ofcourse `parent-demo` decides to override them).

Comment: Great, it all makes sense now, I will use project aggregation.

Comment: You are welcome. Interesting question. I edited to make my answer more complete.

Comment: Until this moment, I've been looking for that answer and just found it. This is the difference between sub-modules and parent in maven. The title of the questions should be more descriptive about this specifically. Maybe difference between inheritance and aggregation in maven. Thank you davidxxx for providing this answer.

Comment: @Anddo Thanks for your feedback. It is right that the tittle could be improved. The problem is that there is another post with a close title of that you propose (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482320/maven-module-inheritance-vs-aggregation) I updated with a variant that is also maven specific.

Comment: nice explanation!

Comment: If the parent resides in a sub-folder besides the child modules, would you have to add the parent to list of <modules> in the aggregator?

Answer (score 2):

Because when you are building some submodule, it should now some meta information, such as dependency version for example, and it's usually a better practice to put this dependencies into parent pom `dependencyManagement`, because I would make all submodules use the same library version. Also there is another meta information that could be useful, like `properties`.

So, all in all when you are building a particular submodule, maven should know some information which you usually want to set up in the parent pom.

I believe there can be more reasons for that, but it's the most obvious for me.

If you want to reuse modules in my opinion then you need these modules to be a library, and add them via `dependency` tag as a library.

Comment: In simple words: parent is for version, dependencies, common plugin configurations, while modules define what projects to build. They can be different. It is useful very often for big projects.